# Devise - when User Update failure redirect to custom page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, routes

How change update user failure route passing devise errors?

Here is my controller code to replace devise registration update:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def edit
    render :edit
  end

  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      bypass_sign_in resource, scope: resource_name
      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource, location: profile_member_users_path(resource)
    end
  end

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    profile_member_users_path(resource)
  end

end
```

I trying change:

```
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  set_minimum_password_length
  respond_with resource
```

To

```
else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      redirect_to profile_member_users_path(resource)
```

But this don't pass devise errros to the view.

Comment: Please post your update code as text and not a picture.

Comment: Can you clarify the desired behavior?  What exactly yo you want to do?

Comment: Call custom path when update user failure. In default my app call edit registration view created by devise. I wanna redirect to another page. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Give me the specific path name and I'll update my answer.

Comment: The logic is equals you use in answer, `location: profile_member_users_path(resource)` but this don't works. Even with this, devise edit view is called when update failure.

Comment: Your code as written will render `profile_member_users_path(resource)` in both cases.  If you want it to render something else, your need to specify a different path.

Comment: Can you post your devise routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cary devise errors with redirect? So then it depends how you use those errors. Devises passes them as a Hash in `resource.errors`. I just tested a bit and this could be your starting point:

```
   else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with redirect_to: profile_member_users_path(resource),
                   notice: resource.errors['current_password'][0]

    end
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my question.  
The errors are in ressource.erros

Comment: Why? I did not know how use the errors without  devise.erros in view. I needed only use resource.errors

Comment: I mean you wrote that my answer answered ur question, but you didnt accepted it, so issue is still open and folks might be trying to solve whats solved :) Thats the Dark side :))

Comment: Done! sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1):

Since you are redirecting, the current resource data is not being passed to the view.  You need to render the view without a redirect.  Try replacing:

```
redirect_to profile_member_users_path(resource)
```

with

```
respond_with resource, location: profile_member_users_path(resource)
```

Of course, this is no different than the original Devise code.  So you need to replace `profile_member_users_path(resource)` with your custom path.

Comment: When i try use location after else, it don't makes nothing. After failure user update, it is render the same devise path(edit)

Comment: What do you want it to do?  Tell me the behavior you desire and I may be able to help.